# No database selected exception occurs although it is specified in the query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a query like

```
    SELECT * FROM dbName.dbTable
```

and I am executing the query using prepared statement.

Here is HicariCP Config Settings:

```
    hconfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    hconfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&cachePrepStmts=true&prepStmtCacheSize=250&useServerPrepStmts=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&continueBatchOnError=false&prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048");
    hconfig.setUsername("user");
    hconfig.setPassword("passwd");
    hconfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
    hconfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource= new HikariDataSource(hconfig);
```

The client usage:

```
    Client client;
    client.executePreparedQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM dbName.dbTable",
                    null,
                    new ResultSetBinder() {
                        @Override
                        public void bind(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
                            // binding the result goes here
                        }
                    });
```

Related method (executePreparedQuery) of the Client class:

```
    Connection con = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        if (psb != null) {
            psb.bind(ps);
        }

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rsb != null) {
                rsb.bind(rs);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        close(rs, ps, con);
    }
```

Although the database to be used is spesified in the query itself, the code sometimes (not always!!!) throws `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected.`

MySQL `5.6.22` is used with `HicariCP`.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the problem. We don't have a magic ball to know what you are doing ;)

Comment: Most likely it expect you to set a default database even if you specify one in the query.

Comment: And also post a Hikari config info.

Answer (score 1):

HicariCP Config Settings:

add => **hconfig.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "yourDatabaseName");**

```
hconfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
hconfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&cachePrepStmts=true&prepStmtCacheSize=250&useServerPrepStmts=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&continueBatchOnError=false&prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048");
hconfig.setUsername("user");
hconfig.setPassword("passwd");
hconfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
hconfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
hconfig.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "yourDatabaseName");
HikariDataSource hikariDataSource= new HikariDataSource(hconfig);
```

The client usage:

chnage to => **"SELECT * FROM dbTable"**

```
    Client client;
    client.executePreparedQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM dbTable",
                    null,
                    new ResultSetBinder() {
                        @Override
                        public void bind(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
                            // binding the result goes here
                        }
                    });
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I cannot remove dbName from queries, because I use the client code to query more than one database. Maybe I should set a default database with and include dbNames in queries as @PeterLawrey suggested

Comment: I see. Setting default database might help.